# Need custom Regular expression for address field

Tags: regex

Need regular expression for address field , which accepts the following

A-z,a-z,0-9, : , - , / space with minimum of 4 character length and max of 200 length

Eg: **Plot No-13,Door No: 3/16b/45**

```
 var regx_name = /^[A-Za-z0-9'\.\-\s\,:\/]$/;
```

Comment: Or `Plot No-13,Door No: 3/16b/45` ?

Comment: more examples would help

Comment: I need regular expression which can accept 
A-z,a-z,0-9, : , - , / space
with minimum of 4 character length and max of 200 length

Comment: @ChaitanyaKoripella vks's regex would match what you've supplied. So would mine. Assuming we were going to just write a regex for you, we wouldn't be able to based on the amount of info you've supplied.

Comment: @ChaitanyaKoripella without any rules .`.*` is enuf

Comment: I suppose you are asking a regex for field validation. Validating an address seems extremely complex because of the immense variety of address formats in the world. Maybe it would be easier to forbid some special characters: `/^[^@!?]$/` By the way, you should not need to escape special chars inside the `[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your new requirement, this should work:

```
^[A-za-z0-9:\-\s/,]{4,200}$
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the ✓ button ;)

Comment: @ChaitanyaKoripella Do not forget `^` and `$` if you need to enforce a length. Plus, there is some useless escaping (you actually authorize backslashes). See more details in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31199847/1734119).

Answer (score 1):

```
var regx_addr = /^[A-za-z0-9:-/,\s]{4,200}$/;
```

or

```
var regx_addr = /^[a-z0-9:-/,\s]{4,200}$/i;
```

### Explanation

From the format in your question, I suppose you are using JavaScript.

#### Authorized characters

Specifying the characters is only a matter of putting them inside `[]` brackets. Notice you do not need to escape the special characters in there (`.*` matches anything, but `[.]*` matches only a series of dots). Actually, useless escaping is only allowing backslashes, which you might not want. You of course need the backslash for `\s` for instance, so as not to confuse it with the letter.

#### Enforcing length

Since you need to enforce a specific length, it is important to start your regex with `^` and end it with `$`.

Enforcing a length is done by adding `{4, 200}` after the group you want to control the length of.

#### Case insensitivity

When writing a regex in JavaScript, you can make it case-insensitive by adding the `i` flag at the end of it.